# how to pass parameters to relationship .parameter passed to relationship from controller to model in laravel.but now working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, parameters, relationship

in my controller parameter passed to posts function in user model with construct method .
i want the users that have posts and posts should be according to the parameter.

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    private $user;
    public function __construct(User $getuser)
    {
        $this->user = $getuser;
    }
    public function index($id = 2)
    {
        $posts = $this->user->posts($id);
        $user = User::whereHas('posts')->find($id);
        return $user;
    }
}
```

in my user model parameter accessed and passed to relationship .

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    function posts($id)
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post')->where('id',$id);
    }
}
```

it works when use like this

> "return $this->hasMany('App\Post')->where('id',1);"

but not working with passed parameter. getting this error

> "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError Too few
> arguments to function App\User::posts(), 0 passed in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php
> on line 415 and exactly 1 expected"

Answer (score 0):

You're making life difficult for yourself and not allowing the framework to do the heavy lifting.

**web.php**

Define a route that accepts a `User` identifier

```
Route::get('/users/{user}', 'UserController@show');
```

**User.php**

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany(App\Post::class);
}
```

**UserController.php**

```
public function show(User $user) {
    return view('users.view', compact('user');
}
```

**resources/views/users/view.blade.php**

```
ddd($user->posts);
```